# how to take input a string of length 10^6 in c++?

Tags: c++, string

we have to take input of a string such as :
1<=|S| <=10^6 (length of string)
and perform some operation , let's leave operation , I want to only know how to take input of such a long string like 10^6 ?
Can we take like this char S[1000001];
or which would be other better way?
Kindly, help

Comment: use a [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)

Comment: @NathanOliver this is an answer, don't you think?

Comment: Simply use a `std::string`, which has a maximum size of [`std::string::max_size`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/max_size)

Comment: That's a whooping 1MB of data! Are you sure a `std::string` will fit? ;-) JK, what makes you think that this size is exceptionally large?

Comment: can we declare like this char S[1000001]; ?

Comment: @Thomas: This answer is so obvious that it seems like we're missing some point.

Comment: @KapilArora: You can. But why would you, when `std::string` is available, which is way more powerful and it's a lot harder to shoot yourself into the foot with?

Comment: Yes you can, but why use a fork to move a mountain?

Comment: You *can* have such a large array, but then remember that local variables (even arrays) are usually stored on the stack and that the size of the stack is limited. On Windows using the Visual Studio compiler, the default process stack size is only 1MB, and an array of a million characters is dangerously close to that limit.

Comment: *"want to only know how to take input of such a long string"* - lots of people have given good advice on where to store it (`std::string`), but as for *"how to take input"* - it depends where you're trying to take it from (e.g. a file, `std::cin`, a socket), and how you know *exactly* how many characters to read (e.g. fixed, or a sentinel character, or a prefixed length in text or binary format....).

Answer (score 4):

Forget about using a c-style string and use a [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) instead.  A `std::string` can hold [`std::string::max_size`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/max_size) characters.  On most implementations today that should be 4294967294 characters.

The benefit with use a `std::string` is that it automatically grows to accommodate the size you need. Since the memory is dynamically allocated you don't have to worry about running out of stack space as well.  You could run out of memory on the heap as you would need about 4 GB of RAM to hold a max size string thought.

Answer (score 2):

> Can we take like this char S[1000001];

You can... but if `S` is an automatic variable, you'll spend most of your stack-space on that one array and you'll probably run out (depending on available stack space and how much the rest of your program needs).

Large arrays like these should be allocated dynamically. Unfortunately, it's not easy to say *how* big arrays/objects should be allocated dynamically. It depends on a few things such as:

- Amount of total stack space which depends on the platform and may be configurable at run- or linktime.
- Amount of stack space needed by the rest of your program. This depends on how deep nested function calls do you have and how much memory your functions need.

I use a few kilobytes as a rule of thumb to decide if I'll need dynamic memory. Or a few dozen bytes inside a recursive function that is expected to go deep.

> or which would be other better way?

`std::string` allocates it's buffer dynamically, provides ways to manipulate the string, makes sure that you don't forget the zero terminator and takes care of mamory management (which would be an issue if you did dynamic allocation manually). I highly recommend you use it.

Answer (score 1):

it depends if the string characters are unicode or not

you could use:

```
   char *txt = new char[1000000]  
   wchar_t *txt = new wchar_t[1000000];
```

also you can try using std::string or std::wstring like  NathanOliver said

Comment: just say no to raw new

Comment: `10^6` does not do what you think it does.

Comment: I didn't want to place 1000000 . why shouldn't I use raw new?

Comment: yes but putting `10^6` is incorrect and you answer should be correct.

Comment: @ficus *" why shouldn't I use raw `new`?"* - because someone's got to remember to `delete[]` (and most definitely not `delete`, or `delete[]` twice, or increment `txt` then `delete[]` and all the other typical mistakes), whereas if you use `std::string` or even `std::unique_ptr<const char*>` then it's inherently deleted properly and can't leak memory.

Comment: @ficus: The issue with raw `new` is then you've added a resource management problem to your code. Better to use a container like `std::string` or a smart pointer like `std::unique_ptr`

Comment: @Tony D , Blastfurnace i know what the implications of using a raw new are. i just was baffled by the first comment

Comment: @ficus: fair enough; just wait 'til you see TemplateRex let loose with `<` and `>`s  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::string`.

Alternatively, if your data isn't being resized, you could opt to use a simple char array. Due to the size of the char array, I would suggest you allocate it with `new` and free it with `delete`. Otherwise, you may exhaust your stack size and cause a stack overflow.